# Parse, inner class, and a Telephone Listener

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

Well I have a very specific and awkward problem in my android application. This is just the onStartCommand method in my service class which when run should create a phone state listener. So every time the user picks up a call I want to send that number to my database in Parse. Problem is I think there is a conflict when it comes to the inner class and Parse. Nothing is being pushed to the servers. I am fairly new to Android and Parse together so let me know if I'm missing something obvious or if there's a work around. 
Thanks

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent e, int flags, int startId) {

    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            Parse.initialize(ParseService.this,
                    "still a secret",
                    "no no no");
            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(ParseService.this,
                    Main.class);

            TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            String userNumber = (String) TelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // OFFHOOK

                ParseObject Users = new ParseObject("UserCalls");
                Users.put("CallsReceived", incomingNumber);
                Users.put("UserNumber", userNumber);
                Users.saveInBackground();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Offhook",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }


    }

    TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(),
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service has Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Add some logs.. also the user class is "_User" in string form.

Answer (score 0):

You're using illegal names for the field (column) of your Users custom object. The column name must only contain alphanumeric or underscore characters, and must begin with a letter. So try something like:

```
ParseObject Users = new ParseObject("Users");
Users.put("User_ID", userNumber);
String callMade = (String) incomingNumber;
Users.put("Calls_Made", callMade);
Users.saveInBackground();
```

It's also not clear whether you wanted to use the built-in "User" class. If you do you'd have to have that user signed up or logged in before saving data to an object. You'd also need to reference it like:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

Comment: Yea forgot to mention that. Fixed it a while back but the problem persists and the class "Users" has no reference to the built in User class. I've narrowed it down to the incomingNumber variable. It comes straight from the inner class but when I remove the Users.put(...,incomingNumber) line everything works perfectly. A new parse object is created with the users number.